# Visual Studio - How to add non nuger library so that it can work with source control (tfs) and not reference local file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, version-control, nuget

I'm working on a Xamarin project in Visual Studio. For this project I want to use a certain library. However there doesn't seem to Nuget package for this library. When I download the library I can add its .dll to the project but I'm afraid this won't work correctly with source control, since the reference will refer to a local file on my computer. Is there a way to add this .dll to the project in a way that will work correctly with source control?

The specific library:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/azure-messaging/

**EDIT: The correct way to do this was using the Xamarin components store available in Visual Studio. It allows for adding references to libraries from compontents.xamarin.com to the project similar to Nuget.**

Answer (score 1):

You could add the dll (the file, maybe in a subfolder "dll") to your project and reference it from there.